# Advice on vendoring dependencies in Go

Tags: go, godeps

I am working on a project that requires some dependencies.  I am a little confused by the best practices regarding vendoring.  Currently I am using GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT and have copied the dependencies into the vendor directory.

https://github.com/jeffellin/machine-cloudformation/tree/master/vendor/github.com

When I need to update the dependencies I checkout the source code manually from docker-machine and copy it into my vendor directory.  This brings in a lot of unnecessary code,  tests, etc.  Is there any recommendations on automating this?  I am used to maven where I can just specify version info in a configuration file.

What about GODEPS?  How does that play into the GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT. I would prefer a solution where I don't have to checkin dependencies into my source tree.

Comment: Check out [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) – its main purpose is to support "go 1.5 vendor experiment". I was researching the vendoring topic recently myself and chose this tool, however, there are other options to consider of course.

Comment: Looks pretty nice,  but if I am reading correctly it doesn't seem to work with specific tags.  Running 


```glide get github.com/Masterminds/cookoo``` 


will basically get the latest commit id from github?

Comment: You have to specify [glide.yaml](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide#glideyaml) and fill it with desired tag/branch/hash.

Comment: is it recommended to still commit the vendor directory?  I am hoping not.

Comment: committing vendor directory makes it easier for other developers to compile your app with just standard Go tools. Also if any of your dependencies is no longer available in the future at the old url your project is safe. In the end it is up to you.

Comment: It's fine not to check the vendor directory, but then you (and others) probably should to stick with package manager of _your_ choice (e.g. glide in this context). There is also [a comment about this](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide#q-should-i-check-vendor-into-version-control) on their github page.

Comment: Sounds good.  Just now trying to figure out how the globe cache is supposed to work. It's suboptimal for our ci system to need to continually re download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few tools that help with vendoring your dependencies. Most of them are able to handle `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT`.

For example:

- [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep)
- [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide)